# I got Error ==> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm running the following python script:

```
print("(Positive Patients ST depression): " + str(pos_data['oldpeak'].mean()))
print("(Negative Patients ST depression): " + str(neg_data['oldpeak'].mean()))

print("(Positive Patients thalach): " + str(pos_data['thalach'].mean()))
print("(Negative Patients thalach): " + str(neg_data['thalach'].mean()))

X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = data.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
```

However I got the errors in the second last line like:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-436d450d7687> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      2 sc = StandardScaler()
----> 3 x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
      4 x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    744                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    745                 else:
--> 746                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    747             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    748                 raise ValueError(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'
```

Can anyone explain a little bit about this?

Comment: Looks like something's wrong with your input data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to scale string data. Though, scikit-learn's Standard Scaler (like a lot of scikit-learn algorithms and ML algorithms) accepts ONLY numerical data.

So, you need to make numerical data from your text data. You may do this by using one of scikit-learn's vectorizers - CountVectorizer, TfIdfVectorizer (recomended). These vectorizers take all your data, split it to the words and assign a numeric value to each word, so you can use it as you wish.

Of couse, there are some intermediate vectorizing techniques, but start with TfIdf.